Could not find AwesomeWebView-Android-1.8.2.aar
`
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugAndroidTestFileDependencies'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find AwesomeWebView-Android-1.8.2.aar (com.github.hzw1199:AwesomeWebView-Android:1.8.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jitpack.io/com/github/hzw1199/AwesomeWebView-Android/1.8.2/AwesomeWebView-Android-1.8.2.aar

`
The attached library is downloaded when clicked, so it is available. but android studio cannot download it.
I tried to change the  implementation 'com.github.hzw1199:AwesomeWebView-Android:2.0.0'
version in this way, but my project requires 1.8.2. Even though there is an .aar file in Jitpack, it does not see it.

My gradle :
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
        
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}



allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

